# Copy/paste UV function is not working?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I want to copy UV from one layout and paste it to another using this functions:

[image]

but seems like paste this functions don't working correctly - when I'm trying to paste it to another layout nothing happens at all. When I'm trying to paste this

[image]

to the same layout, I'm getting this:

[image]

so, I'm just losing a part of UV. How can I just copy this UV to another layout? I don't need to transfer UV to another object, I just need use it in another layout (and I can't understand why I can't delete verticies from it).

Edit: Tried to use magic UV add-on - doesn't work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it seems to be mirroring it on you. Try just selecting the pieces you copied to and well just move the circle over where you want it